# OSX Node.js File upload ENOENT

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js

I've been working with Node.js for a project and everything has been going well until now. I'm using express as well with node. Overall my goal is extremely simple...upload an image to the server in an uploads folder. The odd thing is the upload itself actually works but when I go to use the "rename" function it says the path is wrong/permissions with this error: ENOENT.

I've also tested to make sure that the path is 100% correct when being used by calling the read function to check for the file path. Seems to only break when it tries to modify the file so I've deduced it's a permissions issue (unless there's some sort of special requirement for the rename function). I noticed that every time a file gets uploaded the permissions set to "custom" and only give read permissions to every user except my username. I'll post the code that's related  to this problem below:

/app/routes.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.post('/api/file-upload/:page_id', function(req, res) {
  //    fs.readFile(tmp_path, function (err, data) {
        //   if (err) throw err;
        //   console.log(data);
        // });

    var target_path = './public/images/' + req.files.featuredimg.name;

    fs.rename(req.files.featuredimg.path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.featuredimg.size + ' bytes');
        });
    });
});
```

server.js

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./uploads'}));
```

Everything ends up in the root folder next to server.js in /uploads which works as intended. I just can't seem to modify them. I've tried everything I can think of and have looked up the problem. Hopefully it's a simple fix.

Hopefully someone out there can help me out with this problem. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Make sure you have `images` folder under public. I had similar issue.

Comment: Thanks so much! I honestly thought it had nothing to do with the second parameter as it kept saying the first was the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, a little new to using this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have created *images* folder under *public*. I had similar issue.